# Create new array element only if inner object has different value

Tags: arrays, mongodb

```
{
  FullName: "Emily Clark",
  Details: {
    Income: [
      {
        2021: [
          {
            time: "Sun Apr 11 2021 17:42:39 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
            description: "Web",
            amount: "3700",
          },
          {
            time: "Sun May 21 2022 07:12:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
            description: "Pc Monitor",
            amount: "45000",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        2022: [
          {
            time: "Sat May 28 2022 12:23:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
            description: "Class",
            amount: "4100",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    Expense: [
      {
        2022: [
          {
            time: "Tue May 17 2022 20:30:39 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
            descritption: "Car Wash",
            amount: 4000,
          },
          {
            time: "Fri May 19 2022 10:23:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
            description: "Loundry",
            amount: "300",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Here I firstly added a new Expense Data object to the `Details.Income.0.2021` so it created a new array and object after Income, but after adding new Expense data for a new Year as 2022 it was added to the existing object of first income element, how to create a new array object for new year only if the year not exists?

The second Income element was added by me manually from MongoDB shell.

If the year exist I want the data to look like for `Expense` where it has two Object data for both the same year.

I know this explanation is a little messy but I am willing to provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:
Since `Income` and `Expense` are arrays of objects, and each year is a key inside it, the all solution is rather complicated.

One option is to do something like:

1. add the new item to the doc,
2. calculate the `lastYear` on the `Income`
3. Add a new year if `lastYear` is not the same as the input year `yearString`
4. remove the last year from `Details.Income` in order to edit it. Keep it as `last`.
5. Add the new item to it.
6. Merge it back to the original structure.

```
db.collection.update({
  FullName: "Emily Clark"
},
[
  {$addFields: {
      newItem: {a: "test"},
      year: yearString
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      lastYear: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {$objectToArray: {$last: "$Details.Income"}},
          initialValue: "",
          in: {$concat: ["$$value", "$$this.k"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      newArr: {
        $cond: [
          {$eq: ["$lastYear", "$year"]},
          [],
          [{yearString: []}]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "Details.Income": {
        $concatArrays: ["$Details.Income", "$newArr"]
      },
      year: "$$REMOVE",
      newArr: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      last: {$objectToArray: {$last: "$Details.Income"}},
      "Details.Income": {
        $slice: ["$Details.Income", {$subtract: [{$size: "$Details.Income"}, 1]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      last: {
        $map: {
          input: "$last",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            v: {$concatArrays: ["$$item.v", ["$newItem"]]},
            k: "$$item.k"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$set: {last: {$arrayToObject: ["$last"]}}},
  {
    $set: {
      "Details.Income": {$concatArrays: ["$Details.Income", ["$last"]]},
      last: "$$REMOVE",
      newItem: "$$REMOVE",
      lastYear: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xCpADAueDwM)

If `Income` and `Expense` were an object instead of array of objects it would be as simple as:

```
db.collection.update({
  FullName: "Emily Clark"
},
{
  $push: {
    "Details.Expense.2022": 
     {
        time: "Fri May 19 2022 10:23:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
        description: "Loundry",
        amount: "300",
      }
  }
})
```

Comment: Its giving me the output I got at first stage, i've edited my data, you can see that `Income` array has the first object with value as an array so whenever the year matches it adds to that array of `2021`, but if not then I need to create an object of `2022` and append it to `Income` array and not a sibling to its object

Comment: Did you look at the playground attachment on the original answer? It adds year 2023 since it is not exist

Comment: Yeah I responded after that, it adds the year in the first element of `Income` array but I want it to create a new element for `2022` as shown in my question

Comment: TO be precise it does 
`Income: [{
2021: [{…}, {…}],
2022: [{…}],
}]`
but I need it to be
`Income: [
{2021: [{…}, {…}]},
{2022: [{…}]},
]`

Comment: I see now. Updated the answer accordingly. Please check the updated answer

Comment: Well basically I started using MongoDB a few days ago so your answer is eating my brains a bit, I only did them arrays because it would become easier to map them into my code, i'll rather change my Arrays to Object and map them. Anyways Thanks for your answer i'll keep a note for any future use :)